# Face().boundingBox return negative Rect().left

Tags: android, kotlin, rectangles, android-camerax, google-mlkit

I am using ML Kit to do face detection on live frames from camera. When i tried to `Log` the `Rect()` from the `Face().boundingBox` it returns negative coordinates if the face is in the right side of the picture.

Face detected on left side will return something like `Rect(319, 83 - 558, 266)`
Face detected on right side will return something like `Rect(-73, 81 - 175, 241)`

Rect is drawn from top-left to bottom-right, right? Then why are `Rect().left` and `Rect().right` become lower in value?

Comment: Could you provide an example image and your facedetector options? so that we could take a close look.

Comment: Oh, hello. I have fixed this problem, i need to transform the image according to my display screen size.

Comment: @Shiyu Oh, anyway, is it possible to use USB camera with cameraX API?

Comment: @PaulBrugman can you explain how did you resolve this issue? I've faced it too.

Comment: @NavidEivazzadeh Check this one: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/79903e6a756d3d7473b6aefc5b34829b662e57a3/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/GraphicOverlay.java